# Error while attempting to output data onto console in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, console

I am trying to output general data (source code) from a website, but it just sits there.  Can't figure out if its the interface or the code.  Would someone double-check for me?

```
 #import "Lockerz_RedemptionViewController.h"

@implementation Lockerz_RedemptionViewController
-(IBAction)start: (id) sender {
 while (1) {


  NSMutableData *mydata = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ptzplace.lockerz.com/"]];

  NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:mydata encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
  NSLog(output);


 }
}
```

Comment: A smarter way might be to NSLog(@"%@", output)....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your NSLog doesn't work is it should use format strings.

Replace:

```
NSLog(output);
```

With:

```
NSLog(@"%@",output);
```

For more info see http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html

Answer (score 0):

Why the while(1)?  Are you intentionally trying to set up an infinite loop?  You should just run this once, or maybe set up a periodic timer to reload it every few seconds, but certainly don't use an infinite loop for that... also it's been a while since I did anything with Cocoa networking, but you might want to look into NSURLRequest.  You also may want to try NSData's dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error: and check the error parameter to better see what might be going wrong.  Hope this helps you out.